# How to obtain a certain transition matrix from a non-standard basis to another non-standard basis?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, change-of-basis

The transition matrix, P, from the basis B=$\{(0, 1, 2)^t ,(1, 2, 0)^t ,(2, 0, 1)^t\}$ to the basis B'=$\{(9, 0, 0)^t ,(0, 9, 0)^t ,(0, 0, 9)^t \}$ of $\mathbb R^3$ ?

The solution I got was 
 $$P=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/9 & 2/9 \\ 1/9 & 2/9 & 0 \\ 2/9 & 0 & 1/9\end{pmatrix}$$

I got the above solution using the general augmented matrices method
[B'|B] -> [I | P] (via Gaussian elimination) where P is the transition matrix.

However this is none of the answers in the problem sheet I am doing.

The matrices in the options are

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 & 3 \\ 3 & 3 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 & 4 \\ 1 & 4 & -2 \\ 4 & -2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Any "similar" answers in your problem sheet e.g. transpose of this matrix, matrices with a lot of similar entries to your answer etc.?

Comment: nope, none at all

Comment: I have added the options in the sheet in the question. However, i am fairly convinced all these options are incorrect

Comment: @mathsnerd22 Please use mathjax formatting. Someone already fixed your question, before you added the possible solution

Comment: I don't know how to so i did the best i could

Comment: @mathsnerd22 didn't you see that the last matrix is $P^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

When a vector $v$ is written in the first basis like this

$$v=a_1e_1+a_2e_2+a_3e_3, \ \ \text{which can be written} \ \ v=\underbrace{[e_1|e_2|e_3]}_E\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\b_1\\c_1\end{pmatrix}$$

and in the second basis like this

$$v=a'_1e'_1+a'_2e'_2+a'_3e'_3, \ \ \text{which can be written} \ \ v=\underbrace{[e'_1|e'_2|e'_3]}_{E'}\begin{pmatrix}a'_1\\b'_1\\c'_1\end{pmatrix}$$

Equating the two expressions for $v$, we get:

$$E\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\b_1\\c_1\end{pmatrix}=E'\begin{pmatrix}a'_1\\b'_1\\c'_1\end{pmatrix}$$

which is equivalent to :

$$\begin{pmatrix}a'_1\\b'_1\\c'_1\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{(E')^{-1}E}_P\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\b_1\\c_1\end{pmatrix}$$

And in this way, I find back your transition matrix !

Comment: Are we not looking for P such that $9I x P=M$ ? where M is made of the first set of vectors I have given

Comment: I thought if generally you are finding the transition matrix P from basis A to basis B : it is given by BP = A ?

Comment: If we agree that $P$ is the change of basis matrix, and $M$ is $[e_1,e_2,e_3]$ with the given vectors in column, you have to fulfill $PM= P[e_1,e_2,e_3]=[e'_1,e'_2,e'_3]=9I_3$

Comment: Alright so is it a general formula then that if you are finding the transition matrix, P,  FROM basis A TO basis B then that is always given by PA = B for all bases A and B? Where A is the matrix with the column vectors of basis A, and B is the matrix with the column vectors of basis B.

Comment: Yes, that's it. It is a rare case where we haven't to think "going from right to left"

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SgMd4Np8ps

why does it not work in this question in this video? If you solve for PA=B you get the wrong answer

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is the right way. Don't trust sources that sometimes have different definitions, or sometimes are erroneous. Besides, I have tried to improve my answer by incorporating my last comment in it.

Comment: I am not convinced. I got my solution using the general augmented matrix method for transition matrix from basis B to B'. [B'|B] -> [I | P] (via Gaussian elimination) where P is the transition matrix.

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct

Comment: You are right. I was wrong. Very sorry for the inconvenience (I has in mind a different concept) I have completely written again my answer.

Comment: makes sense now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain this way.

You have, for the basis $B$
$$b_1=e_2+2e_3,$$
$$b_2=e_1+2e_2,$$
$$b_3=2e_1+e_3,$$
and for the basis $B'$
$$c_1=9e_1,$$
$$c_2=9e_2,$$
$$c_3=9e_3.$$
So solving for $e_i$ you have
$$e_1=1/9c_1,$$
$$e_2=1/9c_2,$$
$$e_3=1/9c_3,$$
which subbed into the $b_i$, you get
$$b_1=1/9c_2+2/9c_3,$$
$$b_2=1/9c_1+2/9c_2,$$
$$b_3=2/9c_1+1/9c_3,$$
with matrix specification $P$ as you calculate
but
$$P^{-1}=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-2&1&4\\1&4&-2\\4&-2&1
\end{array}\right],$$
which means that
$$c_1=-2b_1+b_2+4b_3,$$
$$c_2=b_1+4b_2-2b_3,$$
$$c_3=4b_1-2b_2+b_3.$$

Comment: take a look into https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+%7B%7B0%2C1%2F9%2C2%2F9%7D%2C%7B1%2F9%2C2%2F9%2C0%7D%2C+%7B2%2F9%2C0%2C1%2F9%7D%7D

Comment: so what's your final answer?

Comment: @mathsnerd22 the last of the 4 matrices in the OP

Answer (score 0):

> The transition matrix, $P$, from the basis $B=\{(0, 1, 2)^t ,(1, 2, 0)^t ,(2, 0, 1)^t\}$ to the basis $B'=\{(9, 0, 0)^t ,(0, 9, 0)^t ,(0, 0, 9)^t \}$ on $\mathbb R^3$.

A transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$ can be defined as $[I]_{B\leftarrow B'}$ where $I$ is the identity mapping on $\mathbb R^3$.

Check out [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4813465/955582) for clarification about notations, definitions and other related explanations about transition matrix and matrix of a linear transformation, in general.

Let $S$ be the standard ordered basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

$$\begin{align}[I]_{B\leftarrow B'} &=[I]_{B\leftarrow S}\cdot[I]_{S\leftarrow B'}\\ &= \left([I]_{S\leftarrow B}\right)^{-1}\cdot[I]_{S\leftarrow B'}\\ &= \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&2\\1&2&0\\2&0&1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}9&0&0\\ 0&9&0\\ 0&0&9\end{pmatrix}\\ &= \begin{pmatrix}-2&1&4\\ 1&4&-2\\ 4&-2&1\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$

This matches with your last option. Of course, Gaussian elimination can be helpful in finding the inverse.